# Flutter how can i generate release apk?

Tags: flutter

I need to build release apk I have see another answer I run this command in my terminal

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
```

it's showing this  `Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab`

Its not apk file? I need release build apk so can upload on play store

Comment: This is a great question, and I'm sorry that it got downvoted - that is a really annoying aspect of the stackoverflow community lately. I just wanted to tell you that IMHO the question does not deserve those downvotes at all - and I'm glad that you got useful answers.  (The answer from @sidak was what I needed - I suggest you mark that as correct if it is also right for you)

Answer (score 2):

You can just run `flutter build apk` to generate release apk.

Have a look at [this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) for more information.

Also, appBundles can also be uploaded to the Play Store, so the `.aab` file is absolutely fine :D

Answer (score 0):

No worries, you can upload the .aab file just as well.
In fact, this is the recommended way - read here why this is the case: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can run "flutter build apk --split-per-abi", so that it will give a separate release APK for each target platform.